# IOS - Use Custom UI TableViewCell as TableFooter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have setup a UITableViewController with various custom cells - one of which is a submit button - which I need to appear once at the foot of the table.

the cell has the following identifier -

```
 UITableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ButtonTableViewCell"];
```

Can anyone advise on how I could apply this cell once at the foot of my table?  It needs to access a segue also.

I considered using the

```
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

method, but not sure how or if I could apply my cell in this way as that method doesnt return anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delegate methods:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

For viewForFooterInSection return any view you want (it could be a UITableViewCell if you want to reuse that view, and add the some target to the view button).

Just to give you an idea, here is an example:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return button;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`willDisplayFooterView` is only called when this particular event happens. I don't think that is relevant to you in this case.

You can assign a view to the `footerView` property of your table. Or you can increase the `numberOfRowsInSection` count to whatsoever you have in there now plus 1.

Then you add a condition to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to find out if it's the last cell and use your `headerView` cell instead of your normal table cell.